# Empresa pode vigiar tudo que funcionário faz no computador do trabalho?

Tags: segurança, brasil

Vinculado ao meu caso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69324/skype-monitoramento

Preciso de respostas que estejam embasadas em algo além do senso do achismo, tem gente que me diz que esta previsto na lei. Por exemplo:

Na Constituição Federal está, ou não, sendo violada? o art. 5º, XII: “…é inviolável o sigilo da correspondência e das comunicações telegráficas etc...

Há algumas empresas que adotam contratos para que as pessoas sejam informadas e estejam cientes que medidas cabíveis e até mesmo justa causa em caso do profissional seja pego pelo monitoramento fazendo algo proibido pelo empregador.

Estes contratos são válidos, não são válidos? o funcionário pode optar por assinar ou não(sem sofrer penalidades)?

justificando conforme a central de ajuda tópico 5º  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: antes de votar em fechar esta pergunta quero argumentar que esta pergunta é baseada na primícia "dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software" onde preciso saber este conceito de legalidade do software antes de começar o desenvolvimento

Comment: Não vejo como sendo uma pergunta sobre práticas aplicadas ao desenvolvimento de software - esta é uma pergunta sobre práticas aplicadas ao uso de recursos de TI na empresa, o que ocorre em todas as áreas de atuação e não está associada particularmente ao desenvolvimento de software. De qualquer modo: o sigilo da corresponedência é inviolável, mas numa empresa toda a comunicação pertence à empresa e não ao indivíduo, e o funcionário tem opção de não assinar o contrato caso ele não faça questão de assumir o emprego :-)

Comment: Desculpe @SneepSNinjaA Votei por fechar pois para mim esta pergunta está fora do escopo, mesmo se tratando de uma empresa de TI. -- Sobre a duvida, apesar de ter boas respostas, acredito que a melhor pessoa para lhe orientar seja uma pessoa da área, como um advogado trabalhista.

Comment: Esta pergunta está a ser discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3947/est%C3%A1-pergunta-est%C3%A1-dentro-ou-fora-do-escopo-do-site

Comment: Este não seria um caso para adicionar a *tag* [brasil](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/brasil/info) na pergunta?

Comment: @qmechanik editei conforme, muito bem observado.

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada, reaberta e está na fila de fechamento de novo, mas sem nenhum voto para fechar. Achei melhor deixar aberta para não colocar mais lenha na fogueira.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Existem antecedentes. Se o software for entendido como ferramenta de trabalho, é igual a um telefone, e sua monitoração não configura violação dos artigos X e XII do art. 5º da Constituição Federal.

Entretando, os funcionários devem estar cientes do fato, via contrato de trabalho ou comunicação posterior.

Se a empresa falhar na comunicação do fato, pode se configurar uma violação dos artigos da constituição.

Fonte: [Rito sumário 6914820135020 SP](http://trt-2.jusbrasil.com.br/jurisprudencia/24885006/recurso-ordinario-em-rito-sumarissimo-ro-6914820135020-sp-00006914820135020011-a28-trt-2)

Comment: obrigado @OnoSendai era alguma coisa nesse sentido que eu estava procurando, já tenho como montar um alicerce, agora é mão na massa.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Sempre um prazer ajudar. Vale mencionar que as respostas do Gustavo e do Edgar também possuem informações valiosas.

Answer (score 7):

Um contrato de trabalho é um contrato de prestação de serviços entre um empregador e um contratado.

Eu já passei por isso algumas vezes e já acionei meu advogado com essa questão. O que ocorre é que existem questões muito subjetivas. A empresa tem o direito de monitorar o que trafega em sua rede sob alegação de estar zelando por suas informações. Inclusive isso é passível de justa causa:

> De acordo com o Item 7 de Art 482 da CLT, A revelação só caracterizará violação se for feita a terceiro interessado, capaz de causar prejuízo à empresa, ou a possibilidade de causá-lo de maneira apreciável.

A empresa pode fazer isso para re resguardar, mas é importante que isto esteja em [contrato](http://www.leieordem.com.br/direito-do-trabalho-empregador-pode-monitorar-o-que-empregado-faz-no-computador.html) devidamente assinado por ambas as partes.

Ao aceitar o contrato você concorda com a política de empresa. O não aceite dá todo o direito da empresa não te contatar ou reincidir o contrato caso seja uma atualização na política interna.

Infelizmente estou te passando o conhecimento prático, pois sou analista não Advogado. Para uma resposta mais embasada eu sugiro que procure um Advogado Trabalhista.

**EDIT**

A resposta do [OnoSendai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69337/empresa-pode-vigiar-tudo-que-funcion%C3%A1rio-faz-no-computador-do-trabalho/69340#69340) é mais embasada que esta. Vou deixar aqui apenas para enriquecer.

Answer (score 6):

Apenas complementando a [resposta do OnoSendai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69340/23400), o Tribunal Superior do Trabalho vem entendendo que o e-mail **pessoal** do funcionário não pode ser monitorado, mas que o e-mail corporativo, todo tráfego no computador da empresa e/ou por qualquer outro programa atrelado a empresa, sim.

Veja uma [decisão de 2014](http://tst.jusbrasil.com.br/jurisprudencia/121896916/agravo-de-instrumento-em-recurso-de-revista-airr-2683001220085020085/inteiro-teor-121896936) (bem recente, jurisprudencialmente falando):

> Nesse aspecto a autora tem razão. Com efeito, ao compulsar os
>   documentos de fls. 86/91 e 94/96 constata-se que são conversas
>   eletrônicas entre a reclamante e a sua primeira testemunha. Contudo,
>   **não há qualquer indício de que tais conversas foram viabilizadas por
>   meio da utilização de e-mail corporativo ou qualquer outro programa
>   atrelado à empresa reclamada.**
>
> **Portanto, considerando que o conteúdo dos referidos documentos se
>   originam do e-mail pessoal da autora, não restam dúvidas de que a sua
>   utilização pela empresa reclamada fere os princípios constitucionais
>   da privacidade e da intimidade, bem como também o sigilo da
>   correspondência, previstos respectivamente nos incisos X e XII da
>   Constituição da República, *in verbis*:**
>
> 'X - são invioláveis a intimidade, a vida privada, a honra e a imagem
>   das pessoas, assegurado o direito a indenização pelo dano material ou
>   moral decorrente de sua violação;'
>
> 'XII - é inviolável o sigilo da correspondência e das comunicações
>   telegráficas, de dados e das comunicações telefônicas, salvo, no
>   último caso, por ordem judicial, nas hipóteses e na forma que a lei
>   estabelecer para fins de investigação criminal ou instrução processual
>   penal;'